# load javascript files from folder

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure what is the best approach to load all .js files from a folder from within index.html

The number of .js files will change so I cannot define them in the index.html the usual way. I cannot use php or jQuery solutions which would make it easier.

```
<script>
    var count = 1;
    function LoadNext()
        {
             var newScript = document.createElement("script");
             newScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
             newScript.setAttribute("src", "page-" + count++ + ".js");  //Increment    the counter so we get the next page each time
             newScript.onload = LoadNext;  //When the script loads call this function again
             document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript)
         }
   LoadNext();
</script>
```

Comment: If you don't have a server language to work with, you won't be able to accomplish this.

Comment: you think client side won't work. i.e using javascript?

Comment: You can load JS with clientside JS, but there's no way of knowing the file names.  Do you have a standard naming convention at least?

Comment: I would rather load *.js The files will be book.js, page-1.js, page-2.js, page-3.js etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load a new JS file by creating a new `<script>` tag.

```
var filename = "JSDir/JSFile.js";

var newScript = document.createElement("script");   ///Create a new <script> element
newScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");  // Set type to JS
newScript.setAttribute("src", filename);            //Set src, your file to load
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript)  //Append this script tag to the end of your head element
```

If you know your JS files are going to be named `basename-1.js` you can set a callback so that `onload` you increment to the next fielname `basename-2.js` `3`, `4`... and when the final one fails to load it will stop trying to load further.

```
var count = 1;
function LoadNext()
{
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
newScript.setAttribute("src", "basename-" + count++ + ".js");  //Increment the counter so we get the next page each time
newScript.onload = LoadNext;  //When the script loads call this function again
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript)
}
LoadNext(); //Load basename-1.js
```

^^Not tested, but if that way of checking the file exists fails.  You can always use AJAX and check for 404

Comment: thanks for the reply, but sorry I am not quite sure how this works

Comment: replace `basename` with `page` and you should be able to load your page JS files.

Comment: yes that loads the files perfectly. One last question, in the console I get an [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (page-11.js, line 0). Is there a way to fail silently?

Comment: It should fail silently by default but still log it to console.  You could try handling it with `.onerror`